# Shiny R - fileInput Upload location

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

I was wondering if there was a way to modify the default upload location of the fileInput control in Shiny. Right now all uploaded files go straight to the temp folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this problem? I'm facing the same issue right now.